# Why don't child processes produce the same random number if you don't set the seed?

Tags: perl, seed, srand

In the docs for `srand`, it says:

> Another case is that you may want to call "srand" after a "fork" to avoid child processes sharing the same seed value as the parent (and consequently each other).

I could have sworn I never ran into this, so I tested it:

```
$ perl -E 'for (1 .. 8) { next if fork; say rand; exit;} wait for 1 .. 8'
0.301967407417582
0.497966311014356
0.05798998109913
0.907357103963481
0.240495550287054
0.74279685605234
0.368774714022042
0.562179033951001
```

Then I tested setting the seed in the parent with `srand`:

```
$ perl -E 'srand; for (1 .. 8) { next if fork; say rand; exit;} wait for 1 .. 8'
0.13028028358622
0.13028028358622
0.13028028358622
0.13028028358622
0.13028028358622
0.13028028358622
0.13028028358622
0.13028028358622
```

So, if you set the seed in the parent, the children all get the same value. Why doesn't this happen in the first example?

Answer (score 8):

The trick is in when the seed gets set.  It doesn't get set when `perl` starts; it gets set when `rand` is first called.  In the first case, `rand` is first called in each child, so each child gets its own seed.  You can see this if you call `rand` in the parent:

```
$ perl -E 'say "parent: ", rand; for (1 .. 8) { next if fork; say "$$: ", rand; exit;} wait for 1 .. 8'
parent: 0.931186094953777
60700: 0.105917756769003
60701: 0.105917756769003
60702: 0.105917756769003
60703: 0.105917756769003
60704: 0.105917756769003
60705: 0.105917756769003
60706: 0.105917756769003
60707: 0.105917756769003
```

So, if you need to be certain that children have different random seeds, they need to call `srand` when they start (since you never know what code may call `srand` or `rand` in the parent).